# GridView, Images from URL in 2 column

Tags: android, gridview, density-independent-pixel

I am filling a `GridView` with pictures fetched from URL on a background `Thread`. So while the images are loading, the `TextView` below each image is already there, but the image has no width or height. The problem is that using DP is so confusing, I need the images to fill the 2 column grid and I don't know which size is best for it, that doesn't looks to large on lower resolution

Comment: post your layout code, and perhaps a screen shot of what you are seeing and describe why it is undesireable. As your question stands now it is not very clear what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your gridview to have 2 columns, just use the stretchMode to set the width dynamically.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2" 
    />
```

You may want to replace `android:layout_width="match_parent"` by another value if you don't want the gridview to take all the super view's width.